# validacion en jtexfield

Tags: java, java-swing

muy buenas noches, necesito hacer una pregunta muy breve, es posible validar en un Jtextfield que el valor ingresado sea mayor a 0 o menor a 300 por ejemplo ?

resulta que tengo este código y necesito saber si puedo hacer directamente la validación.
Saludos.

```
 if(jtfEdad.getText().equals("0")) {
        int edad = Integer.parseInt(jtfEdad.getText());
        }


else { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "valor ingresado no valido")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

por ejemplo que el valor ingresado sea mayor que o, se tiene:

```
   if(Integer.parseInt(jtfEdad.getText())>0){//aqui cambia la condicion dentro del if
    int edad= Integer.parseInt(jtfEdad.getText());
   }else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "valor ingresado no valido")
   }
```